# Java openCV link error on windows 7 64 bit

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv

I am trying to run a very simple openCV code on eclipse mars on windows 7 64-bit but I get this error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no libopencv_java248 in java.library.path
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
>       at VideoCap.main(VideoCap.java:7)

I tried t add external jars and change the native library to the dlls in openCV java folder and I also tried to set up the environment variable for openCV in windows but none of that works.

Comment: Check my answer .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49581404/java-programming-opencv-unsatisfied-link-error/56320367#56320367

Answer (score 0):

That means that java doesn't found the dll that opencv need to work with certain thing

- Add the opencv-windows-x64.jar to java libraries path may it solve the error

That jar contains many dlls that allows run opencv on your OS.

Comment: where can I find this jar?